# Accessing struct pointer after passing struct by reference to a function

Tags: c, pointers, struct, pass-by-reference

I have this code, however I am unsure of how to access the struct pointers after passing the 
struct by reference into a function, the program crashes on this line,
accessing the pointers doesnt work.

```
    scanf("(%lf,%lf)",polygon->xvals[i],polygon->yvals[i]);
```

FIXED CODE, thanks to all who answered

```
    struct Polygon{
    double *xvals, *yvals;
    int numverts;
    };
    typedef struct Polygon pol;
    pol getpoly(pol *polygon);


    int main(){
     pol polygon;
     getpoly(&polygon);  
            }


    pol getpoly(pol *polygon){
      polygon->xvals = (double * )malloc(sizeof(double)*polygon->numverts);
      polygon->yvals = (double * )malloc(sizeof(double)*polygon->numverts); 

      check=0;
      int i;

      for(i=0;i<10;i++){

       while(check !=2 ){
        cout<<"enter vertices "<<i<<" (x,y)\n";
        check = scanf("(%lf,%lf)",&polygon->xvals[i],&polygon->yvals[i]);
        _flushall();
       }
      check=0; 
      }
      polygon->xvals[polygon->numverts-1] = polygon->xvals[0];
      polygon->yvals[polygon->numverts-1] = polygon->yvals[0]; 

    return *polygon;    
    }
```

Comment: apologies, i didnt explain what was actually going wrong, the program fails where I try to put stuff into the pointers

Comment: I have edited the tags. There are no references in C.

Comment: @n.m. There are no references in the code either; it looks like valid C to me (apart from the missing `return` in `main` of course).

Comment: @Mike: and apart from `cout <<`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No memory has been allocated for `xvals` and `yvals`, they are uninitialsed pointers. `numverts` is also unintialised. You need to `malloc()` space for `xvals` and `yvals` and initialise `numverts`:

```
polygon->numverts = 10;
polygon->xvals = malloc(polygon->numverts * sizeof(double));
polygon->yvals = malloc(polygon->numverts * sizeof(double));
```

and prevent going beyond the end of these arrays, as this code does:

```
polygon->xvals[polygon->numverts] = polygon->xvals[0];
polygon->yvals[polygon->numverts] = polygon->yvals[0];
```

should be:

```
polygon->xvals[polygon->numverts - 1] = polygon->xvals[0];
polygon->yvals[polygon->numverts - 1] = polygon->yvals[0];
```

Remember to `free()` `xvals` and `yvals` when no longer required.